# geometic series with lower bounds k+1 and upper bound infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series

Textbook example says that:

$$\sum \limits_{i=k+1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{i-1}p = \frac{(1-p)^k p}{1-(1-p)}=(1-p)^k~~~~~k=1,2,3,\cdots$$

I'm told that a geometric series identity used to obtaining the above result is:

$$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a r^{n-1} = \frac{a}{1-r}~~~~|r|<1$$

now, i'm wondering how they used this identity to get the above result...

So I pull out the p term because it doesn't depend on i in the summation, which gives:

$$\sum \limits_{i=k+1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{i-1}p = p\sum \limits_{i=k+1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{i-1} $$

which looks similar to $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a r^{n-1} = \frac{a}{1-r}$ where $r=(1-p)$ and $a=1$... but then i'm not really sure how to handle the lower limit of the sum...maybe:

$$\sum \limits_{i=k+1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{i-1}p = -p\sum \limits_{i=1}^{k}(1-p)^{i-1} +p\sum \limits_{i=1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{i-1} $$

$$\sum \limits_{i=k+1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{i-1}p = -p\sum \limits_{i=1}^{k}(1-p)^{i-1} +p\frac{1}{1-(1-p)}$$

$$\sum \limits_{i=k+1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{i-1}p = 1 -p\sum \limits_{i=1}^{k}(1-p)^{i-1} $$

???

not sure how they came up with:

$$\sum \limits_{i=k+1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{i-1}p = \frac{(1-p)^k p}{1-(1-p)}$$

Second, option, ss this geometric summation with a variable lower bound just something i can lookup in a table somewhere?

---

the above was taken out of the exercise:

Let X be a geometric r.v. with parameter p.

(a) show that $p_{X}(x) = P(X=x) = (1-p)^{x-1}p~~~~x=1,2,3,\cdots$

satisfies the equation: $\sum \limits_{k} P_{X}(x_k) = 1$

just in case you need the context of the question...

Answer (score 1):

For an infinite geometric series, the sum is generally the first term times $\frac{1}{1-ratio}$.
Check to see what is the common ratio?  What is the first term?  Look it over, take a minute and see if it makes sense.

$$\text{Let }S_{n}= \sum_{i=k+1}^{n} \left(1-p\right)^{i-1}p = \left(1-p\right)^{k}p + \left(1-p\right)^{k+1}p + \cdots + \left(1-p\right)^{n-1}p.$$  Then $$ \left(1-p\right)S_{n} = \left(1-p\right)^{k+1}p + \left(1-p\right)^{k+2}p + \cdots + \left(1-p\right)^{n}p.$$

If we subtract the two and solve for $S_{n}$, we get
$$ S_{n} - \left(1-p\right)S_{n} = \left(1-p\right)^{k}p\left(1-\left(1-p\right)^{n-k}\right) \Longrightarrow S_{n}= \dfrac{\left(1-p\right)^{k}p}{1-\left(1-p\right)}\left(1-\left(1-p\right)^{n-k}\right).$$

If you take the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$ then $S_{n}\rightarrow \frac{\left(1-p\right)^{k}p}{1-\left(1-p\right)}=\left(1-p\right)^{k}$ because $\left(1-\left(1-p\right)^{n-k}\right)\rightarrow 1$.

So for any geometric series, finite or infinite, you'll always need at least the first term and common ratio and if it's a finite series, you'll also need the last term.  Of course, the commom ratio, $r$, must be contained: $-1 < r < 1$, otherwise, $\left(1-\left(1-p\right)^{n-k}\right)\not\rightarrow 1$.

Comment: so you are saying look at ratio between terms and then use induction? I don't know... i was kind of hoping for the easy algebra solution of look something up in table... co some algebra... then next problem... its really not suppose to be a difficult problem...

Comment: Please see my updated response... I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to use the finite geometric sum $ \sum \limits_{i=1}^{k} r^{i-1} = \frac{1-r^k}{1-r} $
$$\sum \limits_{i=k+1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{i-1} = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{i-1} -\sum \limits_{i=1}^{k}(1-p)^{i-1}  $$

$$ =  \frac 1{1-(1-p)} -\frac{1-(1-p)^k }{1-(1-p)} $$

Answer (score 1):

Just factor out $p(1-p)^k$ and apply the formula for the geometric series directly. You only need a reindexing of a series as follows:

$$\sum \limits_{i=k+1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{i-1}p = p(1-p)^k\sum \limits_{i=k+1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{i-(k+1)}$$ 
$$\stackrel{j=i-(k+1)}{=}p(1-p)^k\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(1-p)^j=p(1-p)^k\frac 1{1-(1-p)}$$
$$ = \boxed{(1-p)^k}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\sum \limits_{n=k+1}^{\infty} r^{n-1}$

$\sum \limits_{n=k+1}^{\infty} r^{n-1} = \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} r^{n-1} - \sum \limits_{n=1}^{k}r^{n-1}$

$\sum \limits_{n=k+1}^{\infty} r^{n-1} = \frac{1}{1-r} - \frac{1-r^k}{1-r}$

$\sum \limits_{n=k+1}^{\infty} r^{n-1} = \frac{1-(1-r^k)}{1-r}$

$\sum \limits_{n=k+1}^{\infty} r^{n-1} = \frac{r^k}{1-r}$